# Combobox selected value return DataRowView

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I set combobox.datasource to a dataview item (so that it binds to a table), When I get return value from combobox.selectedvalue. Error was returned bcos it is of type "system.data.datarowview"

I don't know why commonly its return value as text

The code :

```
 If ldstList.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                        With CbStatus
                            .DataSource = ldstList.Tables(0)
                            .DisplayMember = "CardStatus"
                            .ValueMember = "StatusID"
                        End With
                    End If

If Integer.Parse(CbStatus.SelectedValue) > 0 Then
    GridLoad(Integer.Parse(CbStatus.SelectedValue))
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the issue arises. But I have found a solution:

```
If Integer.Parse(DirectCast(CbStatus.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("StatusID")) > 0 Then
  GridLoad(Integer.Parse(DirectCast(CbStatus.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("StatusID")))
End If
```

Thanks to those who answered, and please do post an explanation or a better solution if you have one.

Answer (score 32):

Regardless of other issues or solutions, please make sure you set the properties of the ComboBox in the right order:

```
.DisplayMember = ...;
.ValueMember = ...;
.DataSource = ....;  // Notice how this one is last?
```

Setting the DataSource property first will lead to "system.data.datarowview" issues.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved my day. Never knew that the order mattered so much.

Comment: I had this issue come up, and found that I had set the `DataSource` before the other two in a few situations.  Setting the `DataSource` last fixed it for me.

Comment: Great answer here.  Right on the money.  I was struggling with some combo boxes that were working fine and others that just would not, until this.  I would also add that you should not attach ValueChanged event handlers until after all of this, otherwise it will get hit when you set the ValueMember, and the value will be null since you have not set the DataSource yet.

Answer (score 2):

You're not binding to the DataView, you're binding to the DataTable itself. The [DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) property returns a DataView you can use:

```
  CbStatus.DataSource = ldstList.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Combobox or dropdown properties go to the **databindings** property...select **advanced**...select text or selected value or selectedItem depending on which property you want to set and then click the **binding** dropdownlist on the top right of the same screen, select the name of the column you want to return for display and after doing that select the format of the data on the **format type** listbox (numeric,currency,datetime,etc) and then click OK. This is assuming that you did set your **value member** and **display member** properties on your combobox or dropdown and this is also assuming that you are not binding via code but through the datasource property of your control (dropdown/combobox)