# Combobox exception "Cannot find column" in Bindingsource Filter

Tags: c#, winforms

There may be a better way to achieve this, I'm just playing about at the moment trying to find the best way to perform a certain task.

I have a C# Winform with a DataGridView and Details on the same form. Independently, this works fine and I can browse through entries and use the tools in the menu that appears at the top. I have added a combobox in named combobox1, and I want to populate this with with values from an SQL table that looks like this (there are additional fields like Site_Address, Site_PhoneNumber etc that I have removed for sake of simplification):

```
Site_ID Client_ID   Site_Display_Name
1          3        Microsoft
2          2        Google
3          1        Amazon
```

I need the displaymember to be the Site_Display_Name but the actual value to be the Site_ID. When run independently, the Combobox1 populates if I comment out this line

```
sitesBindingSource.Filter = "Site_ID = " + comboBox1.SelectedItem + " ";
```

The idea of the above line being that when the combobox is changed, it refreshes the value of the datagrid/details that are on the form. When I include the code I get this exception:

```
System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Cannot find column [System.Data.DataRowView].
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.NameNode.Bind(DataTable table, List`1 list)
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.Bind(DataTable table, List`1 list)
       at System.Data.DataExpression.Bind(DataTable table)
       at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
       at System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value)
       at System.Data.DataView.System.ComponentModel.IBindingListView.set_Filter(String value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_InnerListFilter(String value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_Filter(String value)
       at ImpactMessAround2.Form1.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Gavin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ImpactMessAround2\ImpactMessAround2\Form1.cs:line 46
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.RefreshItems()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
  InnerException:
```

The code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sitesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.sitesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.gavin_TestDataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'gavin_TestDataSet.Sites' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.sitesTableAdapter.Fill(this.gavin_TestDataSet.Sites);
            SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=REDACTED;Initial Catalog=Gavin_Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=REDACTED");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Site_ID, Site_Display_Name from Sites", mycon);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds); mycon.Close();
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Site_Display_Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Site_ID";
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sitesBindingSource.Filter = "Site_ID = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

New error as of 21/07/2014

```
System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.BinaryCompare(Object vLeft, Object vRight, StorageType resultType, Int32 op, CompareInfo comparer)
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left, ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos)
       at System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
       at System.Data.DataExpression.Invoke(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
       at System.Data.Index.AcceptRecord(Int32 record, IFilter filter)
       at System.Data.Index.InitRecords(IFilter filter)
       at System.Data.Index..ctor(DataTable table, IndexField[] indexFields, Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter)
       at System.Data.DataTable.GetIndex(IndexField[] indexDesc, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter)
       at System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force, Boolean fireEvent)
       at System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force)
       at System.Data.DataView.SetIndex2(String newSort, DataViewRowState newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter, Boolean fireEvent)
       at System.Data.DataView.SetIndex(String newSort, DataViewRowState newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter)
       at System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value)
       at System.Data.DataView.System.ComponentModel.IBindingListView.set_Filter(String value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_InnerListFilter(String value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_Filter(String value)
       at ImpactMessAround2.Form1.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Gavin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ImpactMessAround2\ImpactMessAround2\Form1.cs:line 46
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.RefreshItems()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer:

[Combobox selected value return DataRowView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595116/combobox-selected-value-return-datarowview/7885498#7885498)

It is for VB but it's the same idea.

Comment: This was it - thanks. The only other change I made to the code was I changed the selectedindex to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding a `DataTable` to the `ComboBox` so each item is going to be a `DataRowView`.  This line:

```
sitesBindingSource.Filter = "Site_ID = " + comboBox1.SelectedItem + " ";
```

is trying to concatenate a `DataRowView` with a string.  If you want the selected Site_ID value then you should be using `SelectedValue`, not `SelectedItem`.  That's the whole point of setting the `ValueMember`.

By the way, what's the point of concatenating a string containing a single space on the end of that?  There is none.  Don't do it.

Comment: That's what I had in there originally, I was just playing about with it. The concatenation at the end is because I was wrapping the integer in ' ' to see if it made a difference and I'd missed it - thanks for that. Incidentally, I still get the same error even with SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

Jmcilhinney is correct, but the reason why it is correct might be more clear if the code were formatted slightly differently.

```
sitesBindingSource.Filter = string.format("Site_ID = '{0}'", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

The error is, as Jmcilhinney said, is because it is calling ToString() on the DataRowView in an attempt to get a string filter value. I would recommend using string.format as I did above for any kind of string-based filter as it makes what you are attempting to filter and how you are filtering it much more readable.

If this does not work, what is the new error message (as you should be getting a completely different error)? What is the value of comboBox1.SelectedValue just before the exception is thrown?

Comment: This feels like I'm getting closer, I've put the new error into the original post at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change your code from this:

```
    comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Site_Display_Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Site_ID";
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

To this one:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Site_Display_Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Site_ID";
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```