# Combobox SelectedValue Returning System.Data.DataRowView even Converted to String

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, dataset, datasource

I am trying to change value of a `TextBox` control after the value of `ComboBox` changes. My code returns `System.Data.DataRowView` on the first time `ComboBox` value changes. 
That is why I am getting an Object instead of the actual value on first call to my combobox.

```
 private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT donor_name,ID FROM donor_detail",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);            
            DonorName.DataSource = dt;
            DonorName.DisplayMember = "donor_name";
            DonorName.ValueMember = "ID";
            con.Close();
        }
```

And this is Event of change Value of ComboBox which is supposed to change value of my TextBox also when value in ComboBox changes.

```
        private void DonorName_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = Convert.ToString(DonorName.SelectedValue);

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            String sql = "SELECT * from donor_detail WHERE ID=" + id + "";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            MessageBox.Show(sql);          
mobile.Text = dt.Rows[0]["mobile"].ToString();


            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't see you using a textbox anywhere in that second block

Comment: @DrewJordan I added the code of it as well, I removed that line because my main problem is ComboBox is not returning value on its first call

Comment: so... is your problem that `DonorName.SelectedValue` is null?

Comment: No, @DrewJordan `DonorName.SelectedValue` returns `System.Data.DataRowView` when I click on Radio Button and hence it trigger `DonorName_SelectionChangeCommitted` Event which generates exception because my query requires an ID to fetch data

Comment: ah, now I see. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595116/combobox-selected-value-return-datarowview), you should be specifying the display member, then the valuemember, and *then* the datasource.

Comment: Wao, it really works but I do not understand why use datasource at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595116/combobox-selected-value-return-datarowview) and several other places, this happens if you don't specify the datasource *after* the display and value members. This is the correct order:

```
DonorName.DisplayMember = "donor_name";
DonorName.ValueMember = "ID";
DonorName.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: i have specified the datasource after the display member and still get System.Data.DataRowView returned for selectedvalue