# SelectedValue of A Combo box returns system.data.datarowview

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys am having problems populating a combo box whose value depends on the selectedvalue of another combobox

The selected value.tostring method returns system.data.datarowview

The Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtQm3.jpg)

Comment: Please take the time to read: [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595116/1070452  Without code this is just a big guessing game

Comment: And if you use `SelectedItem` instead?

Comment: Might be pedantic, but you aren't examining the `ToString`

Comment: This might be happening because the `ListBox` has been populated using `.DataSource` and the information displayed is the `.DisplayMember` and the value returned is the `.ValueMember`

Comment: Yea David Wilson that's exactly what am using, please am new to Database programming in vb.net. Is there any other way to go about. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Private Sub XOLVE_cboFaculty_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles XOLVE_cboFaculty.SelectedIndexChanged
    If sender.SelectedItem.Length > 0 Then
        MsgBox(sender.SelectedItem.Length)
    End If
End Sub
```